# uninitialized constant error when running tests on Ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Ruby on rails and running into uninitialized constant issue when running tests. This is ROR is created with --api option and this what I've done so far:

After creating models for locations, users, and visits(this is many-to-many table for locations and users),

```
rails g controller v1/locations
rails g controller v1/visits
rails g controller v1/users
```

I ran three command lines to generate corresponding controllers. As you can see, I'm using v1 as a namespace assuming there will be v2, v3 and so on.

Then, I ran the following command line expecting no errors.

```
rails test test/controllers
```

and voila. I'm getting the following error message :(

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 66797
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant V1 (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/sangminkim/Desktop/friend-finder/test/controllers/v1/locations_controller_test.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
```

So... uninitialized constant V1 (NameError)?

Finding it odd, I checked out the auto-generated test file.

```
require 'test_helper'

class V1::LocationsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
    # assert true
  # end
end
```

It looks like ROR doesn't understand **V1::LocationsControllerTest** part...

I tried changing the folder name(v1) to V1 thinking it might be an uppercase issue but no luck.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Update::

```
class V1::LocationsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: Can you please add your controller code here?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Hi Krupa, I've updated the question. It basically has nothing yet because I'm developing this app using TDD. Would it be the reason?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar oh! adding the following codes to the route fixed the issue.
Hmmmmm... what is going on? Does the test expect to have routes?

Comment: Yes @Raccoon When you call controller action in tests it sends an http request to the app and for handling requests routes must be defined

Comment: @KrupaSuthar if you leave an answer, I will accept it ! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Raccoon if you forgot to add a route to your routes.rb then it won't work because when you write any test case like below,

```
test "should get index" do
    get users_url
    assert_response :success
end
```

You send an HTTP request to the application, which will find an appropriate route for it and dispatch that request to specified controller and action for that route.

Comment: thanks! didn't know it required routes to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing your controller to:

```
require 'test_helper'

module V1
  class LocationsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    # test "the truth" do
      # assert true
    # end
  end
end
```

Comment: it turned out that i was missing routes but thanks for your help!