# Test ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant V1::LocationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

Continued from [uninitialized constant error when running tests on Ruby on rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175563/uninitialized-constant-error-when-running-tests-on-ruby-on-rails-5/57179624#57179624) ...

I'm writing test cases for my api controller with namespace - v1 but it seems ROR doesn't understand the namespace V1 exists.

When I run "rails routes", this is what I get:

```
             v1_locations GET    /v1/locations(.:format)                                                                  v1/locations#index
                          POST   /v1/locations(.:format)                                                                  v1/locations#create
              v1_location GET    /v1/locations/:id(.:format)                                                              v1/locations#show
                          PATCH  /v1/locations/:id(.:format)                                                              v1/locations#update
                          PUT    /v1/locations/:id(.:format)                                                              v1/locations#update
                          DELETE /v1/locations/:id(.:format)                                                              v1/locations#destroy
```

and this is what I have in my test file...

```
class V1::LocationControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup()
    # A bunch of stuff here
  end

  test "cannot retrieve a list of locations without a valid token" do
    get v1_locations_url
    assert_response :unauthorized
  end

  # More tests here...

end
```

and this is what my controller looks like

```
class V1::LocationController < ApplicationController

    # To be filled once tests run and fail

end
```

and this is the error message I'm getting...

```
Error:
V1::LocationControllerTest#test_cannot_create_a_location_without_a_valid_token:
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant V1::LocationsController
    test/controllers/v1/location_controller_test.rb:32:in `block in <class:LocationControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/v1/location_controller_test.rb:31
```

It's also funny that I get **page not found error** when I send a GET request to /v1/locations

Mmm... What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your error log it says `ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant V1::LocationsController`, while you controller name is `LocationController`.

Please rename it to `LocationsController` and rename a file to `locations_controller.rb`.

You can get more insights about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646951/singular-or-plural-controller-and-helper-names-in-rails)